# How to implement <mvc:annotation-driven />

Tags: spring-mvc, bean-validation, spring-annotations

I have a trouble with `<mvc:annotation-driven />`. I would like to use for JSR-303 annotation.

Check this image.
http://s7.postimg.org/cz7itmiuj/Beze_jm_na.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc` attribute as well as adding `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd` within the `xsi:schemaLocation` of your opening `beans` element.

Something like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

Obviously, keep the additional namespaces that you have in your current configuration that you're using but are not in the sample above, such as the `xmlns:jee` if you need it.